# Firefox add-on prefetching with link tag

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla

I'm trying to create a simple Firefox add-on to prefetch some webpages. I'd like to use Firefox's link tag to do the prefetching, since it seems like that's the easiest way. Here's my code:

main.js:

```
exports.main = function() {
    var commentFinder = pageMod.PageMod({
        include: "*",
        contentScriptFile: data.url("prefetch.js"),
        attachTo: ["top"],
        onAttach: function(worker) {
            worker.port.emit("init");
        }
    });
}
```

prefetch.js:

```
var start = '<link rel="prefetch" href="';
var end = '">'
var links = [];
var aTags = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")

for(var i=0; i<aTags.length; i++){
    var href = aTags[i].getAttribute("href");
    if(links.indexOf(href) == -1) 
        links.push(href);
}

for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    console.log(links[i]);
    var tag = start + String(links[i]) + end;
    document.head.innerHTML = tag + document.head.innerHTML;
}
```

When I include the link tags in the HTML of the pages I request, they get prefetched, but when I add in link tags using the add-on, they don't. I think the problem might be when Firefox is checking for the link tag, but I'm not sure. Is there any way to test/fix this?

Comment: Where does this code run? Where (to which DOM) do you try to add the link tags? Can we have a complete code example please?

Comment: I've updated the code. It's being run as part of a Firefox add-on. I'm sure how else to answer your questions. Inspecting the page in Firefox shows that the tags are being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through the code, and it appears that `<link rel="prefetch">` elements are only processed when the parser is still active (see the call graph of [`ProcessLink`](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/src/nsContentSink.cpp#664)([hg](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/6a984e21c2ca/content/base/src/nsContentSink.cpp#l663))). Hence it works when using an inline script in a web site, but not using a regular `page-mod`.

You may try to attach the script earlier, i.e add `contentScriptWhen: "start"` to your page-mod options. But you should be aware that at this point there is only the document element present in the DOM, but nothing else, so you need to have your script then wait for other nodes...

Another alternative is that instead of creating `<link>` elements, you could use the [`nsIPrefetchService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/uriloader/prefetch/nsIPrefetchService.idl), by having your content-script message-pass a list of links/referrers to your `main.js`, which would then call the service via `require("chrome")`.

Aside: It might not be the best idea to unconditionally prefetch all links from a bandwidth and performance perspective.

Also aside: Not all links are prefetch-able (`mailto:` etc).

Comment: You talk about using `nsIPrefetchService`. Can you please provide a code snippet, I've been looking and can't find anything about how to do this. Thanks!