# link rel="prefetch" in Firefox network panel?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, prefetch

i wrote this JS:

```
var prefetchUrls = function () {
    var prefetchElements = document.getElementsByClassName('prefetch');
    for (var i = 0; i < prefetchElements.length; i++) {
        (function () {
            var el = i;
            prefetchElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover',

            function (e) {
                prefetchTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    if (document.getElementById('prefetch-' + el) == null) {
                        var url = e.target.getAttribute('href');
                        var link = document.createElement('link');
                        link.setAttribute('rel', 'prefetch');
                        link.setAttribute('href', url);
                        link.id = 'prefetch-' + el;
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
                    }
                }(el), 200);
            });
            prefetchElements[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
                clearTimeout(prefetchTimeout);
            });
        }());
    }
}
prefetchUrls();
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/echo/json/" class="prefetch">Test 1</a>
<a href="/echo/html/">Test 2</a>
<a href="/echo/xml/" class="prefetch">Test 3</a>
```

My script creates a prefetch link tag in the `<head>`on mouseover(after 200 miliseconds) for elements with a "prefetch" class. Works fine so far in Chrome, but theres is no activity in the Firefox Network Panel although `network.dns.disablePrefetch` is disabled(false) and `network.prefetch-next` is enabled(true). Any hints?

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/p05mvzhp/3/)

Comment: I actually wrote a feature just like this for work and I'm getting the same results. It seems that firefox does not resolve dynamically added prefetch link tags. Any progress on this since your original post?

Comment: Looks like this answer confirms my fears: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000598/firefox-add-on-prefetching-with-link-tag